# Haskell Performance Optimization

Tags: algorithm, haskell, optimization

I am writing code to find nth Ramanujan-Hardy number. Ramanujan-Hardy number is defined as

```
n = a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3
```

means n can be expressed as sum of two cubes.

I wrote the following code in haskell:

```
-- my own implementation for cube root. Expected time complexity is O(n^(1/3))
cube_root n = chelper 1 n
                where
                        chelper i n = if i*i*i > n then (i-1) else chelper (i+1) n

-- It checks if the given number can be expressed as a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3 (is Ramanujan-Hardy number?)
is_ram n = length [a| a<-[1..crn], b<-[(a+1)..crn], c<-[(a+1)..crn], d<-[(c+1)..crn], a*a*a + b*b*b == n && c*c*c + d*d*d == n] /= 0
        where
                crn = cube_root n

-- It finds nth Ramanujan number by iterating from 1 till the nth number is found. In recursion, if x is Ramanujan number, decrement n. else increment x. If x is 0, preceding number was desired Ramanujan number.    
ram n = give_ram 1 n
        where
                give_ram x 0 = (x-1)
                give_ram x n = if is_ram x then give_ram (x+1) (n-1) else give_ram (x+1) n
```

In my opinion, time complexity to check if a number is Ramanujan number is O(n^(4/3)).

On running this code in ghci, it is taking time even to find 2nd Ramanujan number.

What are possible ways to optimize this code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First a small clarification of what we're looking for. A Ramanujan-Hardy number is one which may be written two different ways as a sum of two cubes, i.e. a^3+b^3 = c^3 + d^3 where a < b and a < c < d.

An obvious idea is to generate all of the cube-sums in sorted order and then look for adjacent sums which are the same.

Here's a start - a function which generates all of the cube sums with a given first cube:

```
cubes a = [ (a^3+b^3, a, b) | b <- [a+1..] ]
```

All of the possible cube sums in order is just:

```
allcubes = sort $ concat [ cubes 1, cubes 2, cubes 3, ... ]
```

but of course this won't work since `concat` and `sort` don't work
on infinite lists.
However, since `cubes a` is an increasing sequence we can sort all of
the sequences together by merging them:

```
allcubes = cubes 1 `merge` cubes 2 `merge` cubes 3 `merge` ...
```

Here we are taking advantage of Haskell's lazy evaluation. The definition
of `merge` is just:

```
 merge [] bs = bs
 merge as [] = as
 merge as@(a:at) bs@(b:bt)
  = case compare a b of
      LT -> a : merge at bs
      EQ -> a : b : merge at bt
      GT -> b : merge as bt
```

We still have a problem since we don't know where to stop. We can solve that
by having `cubes a` initiate `cubes (a+1)` at the appropriate time, i.e.

```
cubes a = ...an initial part... ++ (...the rest... `merge` cubes (a+1) )
```

The definition is accomplished using `span`:

```
 cubes a = first ++ (rest `merge` cubes (a+1))
   where
     s = (a+1)^3 + (a+2)^3
     (first, rest) = span (\(x,_,_) -> x < s) [ (a^3+b^3,a,b) | b <- [a+1..]]
```

So now `cubes 1` is the infinite series of all the possible sums a^3 + b^3 where a < b in sorted order.

To find the Ramanujan-Hardy numbers, we just group adjacent elements of the list together which have the same first component:

```
 sameSum (x,a,b) (y,c,d) = x == y
 rjgroups = groupBy sameSum $ cubes 1
```

The groups we are interested in are those whose length is > 1:

```
 rjnumbers = filter (\g -> length g > 1) rjgroups
```

Thre first 10 solutions are:

```
ghci> take 10 rjnumbers

[(1729,1,12),(1729,9,10)]
[(4104,2,16),(4104,9,15)]
[(13832,2,24),(13832,18,20)]
[(20683,10,27),(20683,19,24)]
[(32832,4,32),(32832,18,30)]
[(39312,2,34),(39312,15,33)]
[(40033,9,34),(40033,16,33)]
[(46683,3,36),(46683,27,30)]
[(64232,17,39),(64232,26,36)]
[(65728,12,40),(65728,31,33)]
```

Comment: Also package [data-ordlist](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.7.0/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html) could help here.

Comment: @Petr Pudlák Ah - `mergeAll` and/or `unionAll` could be used here.

Answer (score 0):

Your is_ram function checks for a Ramanujan number by trying all values for a,b,c,d up to the cuberoot, and then looping over all n.

An alternative approach would be to simply loop over values for a and b up to some limit and increment an array at index a^3+b^3 by 1 for each choice.

The Ramanujan numbers can then be found by iterating over non-zero values in this array and returning places where the array content is >=2 (meaning that at least 2 ways have been found of computing that result).

I believe this would be O(n^(2/3)) compared to your method that is O(n.n^(4/3)).

Comment: This approach is suitable for the cases where a^3 + b^3 has some known limit. In my case, the limit is not known beforehand. I need to find nth number x for which there are at least two a^3 + b^3.

Comment: You could do this incrementally, i.e. gradually increase the limit and update the array with all newly legal a,b combinations.  The array contents are valid up to the limit so this should have the same complexity.