# Taxicab Numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Taxicab number is defined as a positive integer that can be expressed as a sum of two cubes in at least two different ways.

`1729=1^3+12^3=9^3+10^3`

I wrote this code to produce a taxicab number which on running would give the nth smallest taxicab number:

```
taxicab :: Int -> Int
taxicab n = [(cube a + cube b)
            | a <- [1..100],
              b <- [(a+1)..100],
              c <- [(a+1)..100],
              d <- [(c+1)..100],
              (cube a + cube b) == (cube c + cube d)]!!(n-1)

cube x = x * x * x
```

But the output I get is not what I expected.For the numbers one to three the code produces correct output but `taxicab 4` produces `39312` instead of `20683`.Another strange thing is that `39312` is originally the 6th smallest taxicab number-not fourth!

So why is this happening? Where is the flaw in my code?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32246236/866915

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mistakenly believe that your list contains the taxicab numbers in an increasing order. This is the actual content of your list:

```
[1729,4104,13832,39312,704977,46683,216027,32832,110656,314496,
 216125,439101,110808,373464,593047,149389,262656,885248,40033,
 195841,20683,513000,805688,65728,134379,886464,515375,64232,171288,
 443889,320264,165464,920673,842751,525824,955016,994688,327763,
 558441,513856,984067,402597,1016496,1009736,684019]
```

Recall that a list comprehension such as `[(a,b) | a<-[1..100],b<-[1..100]]` will generate its pairs as follows:

```
[(1,1),...,(1,100),(2,1),...,(2,100),...,...,(100,100)]
```

Note that when `a` gets to its next value, `b` is restarted from `1`. In your code, suppose you just found a taxicab number of the form `a^3+b^3`, and then no larger `b` gives you a taxicab. In such case the next value of `a` is tried. We might find a taxicab of the form `(a+1)^3+b'^3` but there is no guarantee that this number will be larger, since `b'` is any number in `[a+2..100]`, and can be smaller than `b`. This can also happen with larger values of `a`: when `a` increases, there's no guarantee its related taxicabs are larger than what we found before.

Also note that, for the same reason, an hypotetical taxicab of the form `101^3+b^3` could be smaller than the taxicabs you have on your list, but it does not occur there.

Finally, note that you function is quite inefficient, since every time you call `taxicab n` you recompute all the first `n` taxicab values.

Comment: Can u explain why its not in sorted order?